# Insert on specific column using Select then normal struct on other columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, insert

```
INSERT INTO product (pname,currency,other,fields) VALUES ('aNewProduct',(SELECT STATEMENT FOR OTHER VALUES)
```

is this possible, ive tried to search but they all give me like

```
INSERT INTO product (pname,currency,other,fields) VALUES (SELECT STATEMENT FOR ALL VALUES)
```

but i only need specific columns from SELECT and a prefilled column using normal format.. how will this be possible?

Comment: Can you put your constant inside `SELECT`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would do it like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
product (pname,currency,other,fields) 
(Select 'aNewProduct', currency, other fields... From Tablex where blah)
```

Comment: WORKS LIKE A CHARM! THANKS!

Comment: @JosephBada - Hi. If this works for you then please accept the answer so it could be closed. Thanks